# How to sync Moog Sub 37 with my Arturia Drumbrute

Tags: midi, synthesizer, drum-machine

### Equipment

- Moog Sub 37
- Kawai MP6
- Arturia Drumbrute [Manual PDF](http://downloads.arturia.com/products/drumbrute/manual/DrumBrute_Manual_1_0_0_EN.pdf)

## How do I sync these three all together?

I want to Drumbrute to be the master.

When I connect the Drumbrute `MIDI OUT` to the Moog `MIDI IN`, it syncs but it also sends notes i.e. it play Moog Sub 37 notes.

I am pretty sure that I am missing out rather trivial MIDI chaining basics.

Any pointers to get me going will be appreciated.

Comment: Just make sure your "Midi In" plugs into your "Midi Out" and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

In the Sub 37 MIDI menu, try changing the MIDI In Channel setting. If it is set to **All**, trying changing it to **1**. If that still responds to DrumBrute notes try changing it to **2**. If it is already set to **1**, try changing it to **2**.

Clock sync should work even if the channels don't match, because clock messages are not channel specific, but note messages are.

The Sub 37 PDF manual is available here:
https://www.moogmusic.com/sites/default/files/SUB_37_MANUAL_v1.1_0.pdf

Page 35 has the MIDI menu instructions.

> Press the MIDI button to open the MIDI MENU. This menu contains parameters associated with the
>   sending and receiving of MIDI signals. When the MIDI button is illuminated the top right of the LED
>   display will indicate which page you are on, followed by a decimal point, and then which parameter
>   line you currently have selected. Use the [Up Arrow] [Down arrow] buttons to choose a parameter for editing, and the
>   FINE TUNE knob to scroll through a selected parameter’s available options.
>
> NOTE: You can also use the CURSOR button to select a parameter and the [Up Arrow] [Down arrow] buttons to step
>   through the selected parameter’s available options. To exit a parameter, simply press CURSOR again.
>
> If more than one page of parameters exists, continuing to press the [Down arrow] button will take you
>   through the additional parameters and pages. If the MENU WRAP parameter (GLOBAL MENU) is
>   OFF, the [Down arrow] button will stop working at the last parameter of the last page.